# How to transfer files over the same WiFi network between devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, wifi

Is it possible to transfer files via iPhone hotspot i.e, an iPhone connected to a cellular network creates a Wi-Fi hotspot and one of the device is connected to that Wi-Fi and data transfer between these two devices over hotspot?

The iPhone has an app listening to some port or some medium through which the other device can send files to that iPhone app and record/save the files sent from the other device.

Comment: Air-Drop is best to transfer file.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. But this is somewhat like recording voice from one device and transferring the data to the iPhone. The recording device might not be iOS device too.

Comment: I don't think that Apple supports hotspot acess in their SDK. So far, Senthil's comment is the best answer you can get.

Comment: @MichaelOrtiz Thanks. After hours of searching it over Apple, I almost felt the same. Just wondering if anyone has tried it out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

So this finally worked pretty easily using Apple's Multipeer Connectivity Framework. 
Thanks to AppCoda's tutorial, here is the link: 
http://www.appcoda.com/intro-ios-multipeer-connectivity-programming/

This tutorial doesn't talk about Hotspot usage, but I figured out a way to use the same to transfer files using personal hotspot on iPhone.

Steps to reproduce:

- Install the final product of the AppCoda's on two devices. (This
  might not work on Simulator for hotspot check, since no bluetooth via simulator)
- Create hotspot on iPhone and connect the other device through the wi-fi created from iPhone.
- Switch off bluetooth in one device and proceed with the app, browse for other device to connect.
- Try to transfer files from one device to another through the hotspot connection.

Guess what? It worked for me. :) Go ahead. Try it out.

Comment: it is working only for video and image.. i want to send a txt. can i get a sample code